# Não consigo pegar funções da classe System.Management

Tags: c#, .net, classes, namespace

Não estou conseguindo chamar algumas funções da classe System.Management; para meu programa.
Já tentei colocar `using System.Management;` ou `System.Management.ManagementObject` mas também não funciona.

Código:

```
    static string getid()
    {
        string cpuInfo = string.Empty;
        ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("win32_processor");
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();

        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            cpuInfo = mo.Properties["processorID"].Value.ToString();
            break;
        }
        string drive = "C";
        ManagementObject dsk = new ManagementObject(
            @"win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=""" + drive + @":""");
        dsk.Get();
        string volumeSerial = dsk["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString();
        string uniqueId = cpuInfo + volumeSerial;
        return uniqueId;
    }
```

Erro:

> Gravidade Código  Descrição   Projeto Arquivo Linha   Estado de Supressão
>   Erro    CS0246  O nome do tipo ou do namespace "ManagementObjectCollection" não pode ser encontrado (está faltando uma diretiva using ou uma referência de assembly?)   PurePaste   C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\Pedrin Mira certa 3.0\PurePaste\Student\login.cs 73  Ativo

Comment: Usando `System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection` funciona?

Comment: não, não funciona.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LeShift Francisco, Adicione a referencia da lib "System.Management" e depois realize a limpeza e compilação do seu projeto para o Visual Studio carregar as novas libs no projeto;

E confirme que a versão do .NET Framework usada no projeto possui essa lib, se não me engane ela tem como requisito o .NET 4.0 ou superior.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]